# Kernel quits upon evaluation of a limit

Tags: kernel

Using 9.0.1 on OS 10.9.3, I evaluated

```
Limit[(1 + t/Sqrt[n])^-n, n -> Infinity]
```

at the start of a session and it caused an error that made the kernel quit.  But I don't see any warning or error message.  On the other hand, evaluating a very similar expression

```
Limit[(1 + t/n)^-n, n -> Infinity]
```

generates no such warning.  Can anyone reproduce this issue?

Comment: Same issue. the kernel quit!

Comment: Did you see a warning message of any kind?

Comment: Just returns unevaluated for me, 9.0.1 Windows

Comment: Using 9.0.1 on OS 10.9.3 it returns unevaluated

Comment: Now *that's* a puzzle!  O_o

Comment: No warning message. just the kernel quit.

Comment: On Linux, versions 9.0.1 and 8.0.0 return expression unevaluated.

Comment: @heropup is the result supposed to be `1`? (I'm too lazy to think)

Comment: @Öskå: Depends on domain of `t`: Infinity, 1, or 0 for t<0,t==0, t>0 respectively.

Comment: @rasher It has been a long time since I haven't manipulated limits, but it seems like the OP is not playing with `t` but `n`?

Comment: @Öskå: Yes, but unlike the second example, the first does not have one and only one limit, and least not one that can be expressed analytically (hence the unevaluated return). Adding an assumption for `t` gives results, but I've honestly not delved too deep, since the question is about a possible bug/problem and I'm not sure the first example is anything more than a problematic example for the OP. Unless I'm hallucinating... always a possibility ;-)

Comment: @rasher You might be hallucinating indeed ;o) But I highly doubt it :D And it indeed works with `Assumptions`.

Comment: The original limit I wanted to calculate was less trivial; when it crashed the kernel, I went about trying to find simpler expressions that would exhibit the same problem, and a corresponding expression that is substantially similar but does not exhibit the problem.  In any case, the evaluation of such a syntactically correct expression should not cause the kernel to quit, and even if it does, it should at least generate some kind of explanation.

Comment: In Mathematica Programming Cloud, hence presumably in forthcoming *Mathematica 10*, `Limit[(1 + t/Sqrt[n])^-n, n -> Infinity]` just returns unevaluated without crashing. Adding `Assumptions -> t > 0` gives limit `0`; `t < 0` gives limit `Infinity`; and of course `t == 0` gives limit `1`.

Comment: In *Mathematica* 9.0.1 under OS X 10.9.3, I don't get a crash; as output I just get the original limit unevaluated.

Comment: Just as a follow up: Mathematica 11.2 yields `ConditionalExpression[0, t > 0]` when nothing is assumed for `t`.